# Как подключить свой шаблон в существующий контроллер opencart?

Tags: шаблоны, opencart

Задача: шаблон *category.tpl* заменить на свой (измененный). Opencart 2.1, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было по ссылке смотреть измененный шаблон `index.php?route=product/category`
Если оставить название файла *category.tpl*, то новый шаблон виден. Если изменить название шаблона на любое другое имя - **ошибка: пустой экран**.
Меняю в файле: *catalog/controller/product/category.php*

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category1.tpl')) {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category1.tpl', $data));
} else {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/category1.tpl', $data));
}
```

Было сделано по [этому мануалу](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-page-in-opencart--cms-22054).

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пустого экрана не бывает. Либо показ ошибок включите, либо смотрите ошибки в логе OpenCart.

Comment: $this->data['my_custom_text'] - В oc2.x $data['my_custom_text']

Answer (score 1):

В oc1.5.x:

```
$this->data['my_custom_text'];

$this->children = array(
 'common/column_left',
 'common/column_right',
 'common/content_top',
 'common/content_bottom',
 'common/footer',
 'common/header'
);

$this->response->setOutput($this->render());
```

В oc2.x:

```
$data['my_custom_text'];

$data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
$data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
$data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
$data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
$data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
```

$this->render() не используется в Response::setOutput(), вывод шаблона при вызове контроллера:

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/category.tpl', $data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас нет прототипа OC поэтому обьяню на словах

Скорей всего проблема не в этом. В ядре опенкарта есть папка modificate  - вроде так называется. Там есть копии контролллеров которые связаны с модулями и прочими дополнениями.

OC создает xml карты при добовлении модулей( не для всех ) и на их основе создает копии с изменным кодом и помещает их в ту папку, откуда потом и тянет.

Решение проблемы : зайти в админку. В модули \ дополнения и обновить ( в правом верхнем углу кнопка ) . после зайти в настройки сбросить кеш системы

Это должно помочь.

и еще зайдите в system и найдите эту папку ( погугли точный путь ) и посмотри есть ли копия контроллера который редактируете.